# Data structure to preserve insertion order without/with duplicates in c++

Tags: c++, vector, struct, set, stdmap

I have a struct with multiple variables to consider uniqueness. Assume the structure as below.

```
struct Object
{
    // uniqueness considers with following 3 variables
    int Var1;
    std::string Var2;
    std::string Var3;
    // few more variables, not important

    struct ObjectCompare
    {
        bool operator()(const Object* lhs, const Object* rhs) const {
            return std::tie(lhs->Var1, lhs->Var2, lhs->Var3) < std::tie(rhs->Var1, rhs->Var2, rhs->Var3);
        }
    };
```

Requirements:

1. Insert pointers to structs as application runs, hence dynamically grows.
2. Iterate all elements after insertion with duplicates in insertion order.
3. Iterate all elements after insertion without duplicates in insertion order.
4. Find existence of an item.
5. Concatenated keys cannot be used.
6. Pointers are saved in the data structures.
7. std and boost are preferred.

Currently using a collection of data structures as below, which i feel is not the most optimized.

```
std::vector<Object*> vec_WithDuplicates; // preserve insertion order
std::set<Object*, Object::ObjectCompare> set_ToFindExistence;

// Inserted into vec_WithoutDuplicates if not exists in the set_ToFindExistence set.
std::vector<Object*> vec_WithoutDuplicates; // preserve insertion order
```

My question is what data structure/ set of structures i need to use for most optimized and clean solutions?

Comment: I can't think of a pre-built structure that'd help you. your structure seems to satisfy all your requirements, are you having performance problems? optimization is tricky and subject to your exact usage (call frequency, problem size, etc), which you don't provide.

Comment: Call frequency is little high and this resides in a performance critical path. Storing in 3 data structures makes lot of duplicates that one issue. i'm analyzing using boost::MultiIndex and mark duplicates in the data structure itself (variable inside Object) which i can use while iterating to ignore duplicates.

Comment: boost.multiindex should work for this.

Comment: Can boost.multiindex keep duplicates as well?